Python - googletrans | 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
I'm trying to translate my dataset to eng - it contains datas on some different languages, then first i wrote this:
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect


df = pd.read_csv('jobs.csv')
def detect_language(text):
    try:
        return detect(text)
    except:
        return None

df['language'] = df['job_title'].apply(detect_language)

print(df.head())

then try to tranlate languages which is not eng to eng
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_to_english(text):
    if pd.isnull(text):
        return text
    else:
        translator = Translator()
        translated = translator.translate(text, src='auto', dest='en')
        return translated.text

english_jobs = df[df['language'] == 'en']

non_english_jobs = df[df['language'] != 'en']
non_english_jobs['translated_job_title'] = non_english_jobs['job_title'].apply(translate_to_english)

translated_df = pd.concat([english_jobs, non_english_jobs])

print(translated_df.head())


but second one gives an error like this:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 20
     18 # Translate non-English text to English
     19 non_english_jobs = df[df['language'] != 'en']
---> 20 non_english_jobs['translated_job_title'] = non_english_jobs['job_title'].apply(translate_to_english)
     22 # Concatenate English and translated non-English jobs
     23 translated_df = pd.concat([english_jobs, non_english_jobs])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Can you help me to solve that problem, please?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

If you can give us dummy df would be nice

Firstly I have tested with that and as I see main problem is came from googletrans. I used deep-translator instead of that.
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator 

I've created dummy df for checking my code.
data = {'job_title': ["Software Engineer", "Ingeniero de Software", "Développeur logiciel", "Data Scientist", "Gerente de Proyecto"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Used lambda instead of detect_language(text):
df['language'] = df['job_title'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) if x is not None else None)

def translate_to_english(text):
    if pd.isnull(text):  
        return text
    else:
        try:
            translator = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en')
            translated = translator.translate(text)
            return translated
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error translating '{text}': {e}")
            return None

non_english_jobs = df[df['language'] != 'en']

I created a copy before modification to handle SettingWithCopyWarning.
non_english_jobs_copy = non_english_jobs.copy()  
non_english_jobs_copy['translated_job_title'] = non_english_jobs_copy['job_title'].apply(translate_to_english)

translated_df = pd.concat([df[df['language'] == 'en'], non_english_jobs_copy])
print(translated_df.head())

Output is like :
               job_title language translated_job_title
0      Software Engineer       en                  NaN
1  Ingeniero de Software       de    Software engineer
2   Développeur logiciel       fr   Software developer
3         Data Scientist       it       Data Scientist
4    Gerente de Proyecto       es      Project Manager

Hope this solution may help you on project.
